# Сворачивание клавиатуры EditText в recyclerview

Tags: android, edittext

> У меня создан recyclerview в котором несколько EditText, при изменении
>   одного EditText по заданному правилу изменяются все другие через
>   onTextChanged.

Собственно сама проблема: Клавиатура установлена как `<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />`. После выбора одного из EditText или ввода в него, клавиатура развернута. Если в этот момент совершить прокрутку и выбранный ранее EditText пропадает из области отрисовки, вместо открытой number клавиатуры появляется буквенная, если прокрутить обратно и тот самый EditText снова отрисуется, клавиатура number вернется.

Получается чтобы избежать такого поведения, нужно чтобы при изменении отрисовки recyclerview клавиатура сворачивалась? На сколько я понял, в адаптере за это отвечает onBindViewHolder? Пока-что не удалось скрыть клавиатуру оттуда, пожалуйста помогите.

Получилось скрыть через onFocusChange, но после первого же ввода в EditText клавиатура тоже сворачивается, т.е. не вариант как я понимаю в данном случае...

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.editid && !hasFocus) {
                   InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(v.getContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onBindViewHolder вам вряд ли поможет получить вменяемый результат, т.к. срабатывает на каждое появление нового элемента сверху или снизу. Я бы предложил адаптер вообще не трогать,  а создать свой класс наследованный от RecyclerView и в методе onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) если event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE - скрываем клавиатуру. То есть когда юзер начинает руками тащить список - клавиатура скрывается. Как-то так будет:

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
   public MyRecyclerView (Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
   }

   public MyRecyclerView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
   }

   public MyRecyclerView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            this.hideKeyboard((Activity)getContext());
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
   }

   private void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(View(activity).getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. MyRecyclerView работает, но скрыть клавиатуру не удалось (ругается на view в view.getWindowToken(), не совсем понятно как его получить здесь, MyRecyclerView определен во фрагменте). Пробовал убрать view оставив только getWindowToken(), так клавиатура не исчезает.

Comment: Из проекта не целиком скопировал, не проверил на достаточность. Вообще брал вроде отсюда в свое время решение. Если разберетесь рпньше меня что я там не доделал - скажите, изменю ответ https://stackoverflow.com/q/1109022/11403490

Comment: Понял где ошибся, поправил hideKeyboard в ответе. Так должно работать

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку, с ней смог заставить работать. 1) В onInterceptTouchEvent убрал if оставив просто его содержимое (в ваш if вообще не попадало во время работы, без него всё как надо). 2) Реализацию hideKeyboard сделал такую как в ответе по ссылке. Спасибо за помощь, наверное не додумался бы сделать через extends RecyclerView